What is the so-called momentum density?
What is the so-called momentum density? I am reading the paper by Pitaevskii, in which he stated that it is well-known. He studied the nonlinear Schroedinger equation, but it seems that the concepts applies to the linear Schroedinger equation too.


Does this answer your question? What is "momentum density" and why it important to QFT?

@JohnRennie   No. I think invoking QFT is far-fetched here. We should can do everything in the framework of the Schroedinger equation.
